# Fetching contacts in android is very slow

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I had written a code to fetch contact name, phone number and image from Contacts and to display it on a listview in android. It's working fine but taking more time to load. I had tried to use multi-threading in some parts of the code. But the loading time is not decreased.

Here is the `onCreate()` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 lvDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

 fetchcontacts();

 lvDetail.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList));
 }
```

Here is the code for fetch contacts:

```
  private void fetchcontacts() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
                int count = cursor.getCount();
                if (count > 0) {
                     Toast.makeText(context, "count >0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String columnId = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
                        int cursorIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnId);
                        String id = cursor.getString(cursorIndex);

                      name = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                      Toast.makeText(context, "Toast 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                        int numCount = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                        if (numCount > 0) {
                             Toast.makeText(context, "Toast 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+" = ?", new String[] { id
                }, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

                                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                     Toast.makeText(context, "Toast 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              phoneNo = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.
                Phone.NUMBER));


                                String image_uri = phoneCursor
                                         .getString(phoneCursor
                                         .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

                             if (image_uri != null) {
                                 Toast.makeText(context, "Toast 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 System.out.println(Uri.parse(image_uri));
                                 try {
                              bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                                 .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
                                 Uri.parse(image_uri));
                                // sb.append("\n Image in Bitmap:" + bitmap);
                                // System.out.println(bitmap);

                                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                 } catch (IOException e) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                 }

                                 }
                             Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    getDataInList(name,phoneNo,bitmap);
                                 name=null;
                                 phoneNo=null;
                                 Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star1);
                                 bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();



                                    }
                                    phoneCursor.close();
                                }

                            }


                        }
```

Here the setAdapter() function of the listview is working after fetching all the contacts to an ArrayList. do anyone have idea about how to display the contacts during fetching contacts? any sample code?

Answer (score 5):

1.Read the **Columns** from the `Cursor` which you required only ,According to your requirement you just need **_ID,HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,DISPLAY_NAME** ,so change the Cursor reading

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

2.Dont do the time taking process in the UI thread..Use `AsyncTask` instead

**Note** : This two steps will resolve to some extent..but not completely

Comment: I had tried this. But I did not find any noticeable change. Here the setAdapter() function of the listview is working after fetching all the contacts to an ArrayList. Do you have any idea about how to display the contacts during fetching contacts?

Answer (score 2):

I made it by reduce repeated query wich is expensive. Best of my solution is that method found all mobile phones and email for each contact and insert to list for every contact values. It is fast as storm now :)

```
//contact entity
public class MobileContact {
    public String name;
    public String contact;
    public Type type;

    public MobileContact(String contact, Type type) {
        name = "";
        this.contact = contact;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public MobileContact(String name, String contact, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public enum Type {
        EMAIL, PHONE
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MobileContact{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", contact='" + contact + '\'' +
                ", type=" + type +
                '}';
    }
}

// method for collect contacts
public List<MobileContact> getAllContacts() {
        log.debug("get all contacts");
        List<MobileContact> mobileContacts = new ArrayList<>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        // add all mobiles contact
        Cursor phonesCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID}, null, null, null);
        while (phonesCursor != null && phonesCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = phonesCursor.getString(phonesCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String phoneNumber = phonesCursor.getString(phonesCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replace(" ", "");
            mobileContacts.add(new MobileContact(contactId, phoneNumber, MobileContact.Type.PHONE));
        }
        if (phonesCursor != null) {
            phonesCursor.close();
        }

        // add all email contact
        Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID}, null, null, null);
        while (emailCursor != null && emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID));
            String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            mobileContacts.add(new MobileContact(contactId, email, MobileContact.Type.EMAIL));
        }
        if (emailCursor != null) {
            emailCursor.close();
        }

        // get contact name map
        Map<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<>();
        Cursor contactsCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER}, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (contactsCursor != null && contactsCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String contactName = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contactMap.put(contactId, contactName);
        }
        if (phonesCursor != null) {
            phonesCursor.close();
        }


        // replace contactId to display name
        for (MobileContact mobileContact : mobileContacts) {
            String displayName = contactMap.get(mobileContact.name);
            mobileContact.name = displayName != null ? displayName : "";
        }

        // sort list by name
        Collections.sort(mobileContacts, new Comparator<MobileContact>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MobileContact c1, MobileContact c2) {
                return c1.name.compareTo(c2.name);
            }
        });

        return mobileContacts;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The contacts in larse size use in backround task.
   Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number[i]));

```
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Cursor search = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (search != null && search.getCount() > 0) {
                search.moveToNext();
                name = search.getString(search.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                id = search.getString(search.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));
                System.out.println("name" + name + "id" + id);
           /* tv_name.setText(name);
            tv_id.setText(id);
            tv_phone.setText(number);*/
            }
        } finally {
            if (search != null) {
                search.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way for me soo far .

```
ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver(); Cursor cursor= mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, "HAS_PHONE_NUMBER <> 0", null, null); if (cursor!= null) { final int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME); final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER); final int idIndex= cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID); String displayName, number = null, idValue; while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
   idValue= cursor.getString(idIndex);
   Cursor phones  = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, "contact_id = '" + idValue + "'", null, null);
   phones.moveToFirst();
   try {
   number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
   }
   catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
   {`
   }
   phones.close();
   userList.add(new ContactModel(displayName , number , null , }
```